# What's the rule to use class "entry" on html

Tags: html

```
<div class="entry"></div>
```

This class entry usually placed for main article of a page/post (not homepage). Is there any possibility to use it beside for main article of a page/post? I know I can use it multiple times on homepage, but can I use it for aside or section? for sidebar's list or related posts' list? What the rule to use `class="entry"`?

I've been searching on Google for an hour and can't find this kind of thing. Thanks!

Comment: The reason you can't find anything is because there is no rule about such a thing.

Comment: Why am I downvoted? I'm asking because I don't know and can't find find it anywhere. Okay if there's no rule about it

Comment: By design, there are no standard rules in HTML for values of the `class` attribute—not for `class=entry` or anything else. So if you want to use `class=entry` for an `aside` or `section`, go for it.

Comment: @sevenseacat you make my day

Comment: @sideshowbarker Awesome! so most blog posts using `class=entry` only because it's convenient to use it for its content. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes), `class` is an optional attribute that contains a set of [space-separated tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens) representing the different classes that the given element belongs to. And notably (emphasis mine):

> **There are no additional restrictions on the tokens authors can use in the `class` attribute**, but authors are encouraged to use values that describe the nature of the content, rather than values that describe the desired presentation of the content.

Shortly put, this means you can use whatever class names you like.

The class `entry` may be common because there are many cases where it conforms to the recommendation half of the above excerpt: it's an easily understandable verbose description of the content contained.

Comment: Sooo.. `class` attributes rule only happen when using Microformats? Get it now. Thanks for the link, I often go to w3.org, but only for its validator :p

Comment: That's specific to Microformats, but I'm not all that familiar with their approach.